# How to read HTTP response headers from web service response?

Tags: c#, web-services, response-headers

How can I read the HTTP response headers from a web service response in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through MSDN, all I needed to do was to override the `GetWebResponse` method, and then I could access the response headers:

```
public class MyWSProxy : HttpWebClientProtocol
{
    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        System.Net.WebResponse wr = base.GetWebResponse(request);

        // read a response header
        object val = wr.Headers["key"];

        return wr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just refer to `HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers` in your webservice?
I'm not sure if that'll work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting back an `HttpResponse`, you can just query the [`HttpResponse.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx) property.